# Ask the user before submitting the form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, razor, controller, onsubmit

I have a cshtml page with this code:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("ExportExcel", "Records")' method="post" target="_blank" onsubmit="return exportExcel(), true">
            <input type="hidden" name="filteredRecordsIds" id="filteredRecordsIds" value="" />
            <input id="btnExportExcel" type="submit" hidden="hidden" />
        </form>
```

in js the exportExcel function:

```
function exportExcel() {
 $('#filteredRecordsIds').val(filteredRecords.map(function (record) { return record.Id }));
    return true;
}
```

in controller Records:

```
public ActionResult ExportExcel(string filteredRecordsIds)
        {...}
```

I would like to add modal/popup, before the submitting that ask the user:

"Would you like to export with calculations?" with 2 buttons options: "Yes" or "No".

Depending on the user's response, I would like to send the answer to the controller (as second parameter).

How can I add that?

Thank You!

Comment: If you want to prevent the immediate communication with the server on submit, you have to use AJAX,  need to get rid of the action attribute, use, `preventDefault` on submit, and manage the communication inside a custom AJAX function. You can use a simple `prompt` to ask a confirmation to the user, or a custom modal made in html/css/js.

Comment: Thanks. can you give me / refer me to example? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to remove onsubmit,and use a button to open modal,then calling exportExcel when clicking Yes button:

```
<form action='@Url.Action("ExportExcel", "Records")' method="post" target="_blank" id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="filteredRecordsIds" id="filteredRecordsIds" value="" />
    <input id="btnExportExcel" type="button" value="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong"/>
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Would you like to export with calculations?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="exportExcel()">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js(submit the form in exportExcel):

```
function exportExcel() {
            $('#filteredRecordsIds').val(filteredRecords.map(function (record) { return record.Id }));
            $("#myForm").submit();
        }
```